# Send form data to client side function to retrieve a page title

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I'm attempting to pull the title from the metadata of a URL on the client side so it appears in real time (much like pasting a link on FB / Twitter). However I am struggling to load the url from an input and send the data to a function to make it read on console.log without having to submit the form yet.

Jade

```
form(method='post' action='/submit', class='plans', id='plans')
      .form-group
        label Do you have a link?
        input.form-control(name='link', type='url', required='required', onchange='scrapeMetadata();', onkeyup='this.onchange();', onpaste='this.onchange();', oninput='this.onchange();')
```

JS

```
function scrapeMetadata(link) {
    var url = link;
    console.log(url)
};
```

Comment: If I understand you problem correctly, you may have CORS issues...
If so, use `$.ajax()` to ask your server...

Answer (score 0):

Server-side, have the browser send the url via ajax and display that.
Like in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mo0qa8yk

```
function getTitle(url) {
  try {
    return new window.URL(url).host;
  } catch(ex) {
    console.error(ex);
    return 'N/A';
  }
}

window.scrapeMetadata = function () {
  var url = $('#url').val();
  $.ajax({
   type: 'GET',
    url: '//jsfiddle.net/echo/jsonp/',
    data: {
        url: url,
        title: getTitle(url) //cheat , the server sould return {title:'...'}
    },
    async: false,
    jsonpCallback: 'jsonCallback',
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: show_response,
    error: function(e) {
       console.error(e.message);
    }
  });

};



show_response = function(obj) {
  var result = $('#post');  
  result.html("");
  result.append('<li>' + obj.title + '</li>')
};
```